# How is the execution_date of a DagRun set?

Tags: airflow

Given a `DAG` having an `start_date`, which is run at a specific date, how is the `execution_date` of the corresponding `DAGRun` defined?

I have read the [documentation](https://airflow.apache.org/scheduler.html#backfill-and-catchup) but one example is confusing me:

```
"""
Code that goes along with the Airflow tutorial located at:
https://github.com/airbnb/airflow/blob/master/airflow/example_dags/tutorial.py
"""
from airflow import DAG
from airflow.operators.bash_operator import BashOperator
from datetime import datetime, timedelta


default_args = {
    'owner': 'airflow',
    'depends_on_past': False,
    'start_date': datetime(2015, 12, 1),
    'email': ['airflow@example.com'],
    'email_on_failure': False,
    'email_on_retry': False,
    'retries': 1,
    'retry_delay': timedelta(minutes=5),
    'schedule_interval': '@hourly',
}

dag = DAG('tutorial', catchup=False, default_args=default_args)
```

Assuming that the `DAG` is run on 2016-01-02 at 6 AM, the first `DAGRun` will have an `execution_date` of 2016-01-01 and, as said in the documentation

> the next one will be created just after midnight on the morning of
>   2016-01-03 with an execution date of 2016-01-02

Here is how I would have set the `execution_date`:

the `DAG` having its `schedule_interval` set to every hour and being run on 2016-01-02 at 6 AM, the `execution_date` of the first `DAGRun` would have been set to 2016-01-02 at 7 AM, the second to 2016-01-02 at 8 AM ...ect.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is just how scheduling works in Airflow. I think it makes sense to do it the way that Airflow does when you think about how normal ETL batch processes run and how you use the `execution_date` to pick up delta records that have changed.

Lets say that we want to schedule a batch job to run every night to extract new records from some source database. We want all records that were changed from the 1/1/2018 onwards (we want all records changed on the 1st too). To do this you would set the start_date of the DAG to the 1/1/2018, the scheduler will run a bunch of times but when it gets to 2/1/2018 (or very shortly after) it will run our DAG with an `execution_date` of 1/1/2018.

Now we can send an SQL statement to the source database which uses the `execution_date` as part of the SQL using JINJA templating. The SQL would look something like:

```
SELECT row1, row2, row3
FROM table_name
WHERE timestamp_col >= {{ execution_date }} and timestamp_col < {{ next_execution_date }}
```

I think when you look at it this way it makes more sense although I admit I had trouble trying to understand this at the beginning.

Here is a quote from the documentation https://airflow.apache.org/scheduler.html:

> The scheduler runs your job one schedule_interval AFTER the start date, at the END of the period.

Also it's worth noting that the example you're looking at from the documentation is describing the behaviour of the schedule when backfilling is disabled. If backfilling was enabled there would be a DAG run created for every 1 hour interval between 1/12/2015 and the current date if the DAG had never been run before.

Comment: thanks for the reply. Yes I took the example when the backfilling was set to `False`. Still, the scheduling should be on each hour (because it is set like that in the definition of the DAG) not every day like stated in the documentation. According to the doc, the backfilling also changes the `schedule_interval` (hourly to daily)l

Comment: I found a [youtube video](https://youtu.be/4iDjegukrkI?t=1994)  that illustrates your ETL example

Comment: I think the confusion really stems from the fact that it is called "execution_date" - this would suggest that this is when the job has actually been run. I think a better name for it would have been "interval_start" and "interval_end" but dunno, probably a reason for it that I cant think of right now. The original design of Airflow was around scheduling ETL jobs so it makes sense (albeit confusing for beginners) to do it this way, when you start using Airflow for non-ETL work it becomes even more confusing!

Answer (score 3):

We get this question a lot from analysts writing airflow dags.

Each dag run covers a ***period of time*** with a start & end.

The start = execution_date

The end   = when the dag run is created and executed (*next_execution_date*)

An example that should help:

```
Schedule interval: '0 0 * * *' (run daily at 00:00:00 UTC)
Start date: 2019-10-01 00:00:00

10/1 00:00           10/2 00:00
*<------------------>*
 < your 1st dag run >
^ execution_date
  next_execution_date^
                     ^when this 1st dag run is actually created by the scheduler
```

As @simond pointed out in a comment, "execution_date" is a poor name for this variable. It is neither a date nor represents when it was executed. Alas we're stuck with what the creators of airflow gave us... I find it helpful to just use next_execution_date if I want the datetime the dag run will execute my code.